# Any chance of compiling ROS 2 from sources now

Tags: ros, ros2, ardent

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had problems compiling the latest release, [solved](https://answers.ros.org/question/302360/can-not-compile-ros-2-cmake-error-installexport-given-unknown-export-has_library_target/?answer=302403#post-id-302403) **(not really - see the update)** by switching to the latest master, but the latter brought other problems, purpotedly caused by some machine-generated code:

```
$ colcon build --symlink-install
...
Starting >>> rosidl_generator_cpp                                                                                           
Finished <<< class_loader [2.10s]                                                                                                                         
Starting >>> rosidl_typesupport_introspection_c
--- stderr: rosidl_generator_cpp                                                                                                                           
/home/art/ros2_ws/build/rosidl_generator_cpp/rosidl_generator_c/rosidl_generator_cpp/msg/string_arrays__functions.c: In function ‘rosidl_generator_cpp__msg__StringArrays__init’:
/home/art/ros2_ws/build/rosidl_generator_cpp/rosidl_generator_c/rosidl_generator_cpp/msg/string_arrays__functions.c:52:47: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘rosidl_generator_c__String {aka struct rosidl_generator_c__String}’ from type ‘char *’
   msg->def_string_dynamic_array_value.data[0] = "What";
                                               ^
...
```

I wonder, how can I compile ROS 2 now from sources? I would need one which works with the RTI Connext DDS.

**================== UPDATE**

This is a parallel build, sometimes [the same error shows](https://answers.ros.org/question/302360/can-not-compile-ros-2-cmake-error-installexport-given-unknown-export-has_library_target/?answer=302403#post-id-302403) as with release-latest.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/302458/any-chance-of-compiling-ros-2-from-sources-now/) by [uthinu](https://answers.ros.org/users/37306/uthinu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 118 on 2018-09-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2018-09-05**:
If you don't need the latest changes from master you should stick to the latest release - Bouncy. Anyway both states build just fine for other as well as the CI system. There might be a problem in your process. Please post all exact steps you are doing "from scratch" and mention your platform.

**Comment by [uthinu](https://answers.ros.org/users/37306/uthinu/) on 2018-09-05**:
I am on xenial (precisely, Ubuntu 16-based linux mint, but if it matters, ros would be the first app I know which cares) but anyway I was told that Bouncy is for Ubuntu 18. I will upgrade to Ubuntu 18-based mint and start from scratch.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-09-05**:
Bouncy can be built from sources on Xenial (see [REP-2000: ROS 2.0 Target Platforms](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-2000.html#bouncy-bolson-june-2018-june-2019)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I switched to Bouncy as suggested by the commenters. This time, I also removed ardent installed via ubuntu. Then I reiterated https://github.com/ros2/ros2/wiki/Linux-Development-Setup. Whatever was the problem before, now it worked fine.

By the way, rosdep uses a distro name and not a ubuntu codename. So if you install on a derivative like Linux mint, add e.g. `--os=ubuntu:xenial` depending on which version of ubuntu your distro is based.

---

Originally posted by [uthinu](https://answers.ros.org/users/37306/uthinu/) with karma: 118 on 2018-09-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0